# IOS Application Settings and Text/HTML

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, settings

Hi I am trying to show a large amount of static text within the applications settings on the iPhone. I have seen an iPhone app accomplish this and I am trying to achieve the same result. The goal being if the user navigates to the applications settings page, and they can view the terms and conditions.

Any pointers? I can show a Title or MultiValue strings - but these only allow short strings to display. Ideally it should open a full page formatted perhaps with HTML - or line breaks.

I would like this to be available from the iPhone settings for the app (outside of the app iteself). Presumably using the settings bundle & Root.plist.

Comment: You can just use an `UITextView`

Comment: Thankyou for your responses. What i am really after is how to do this in the settings bundle - so it can be viewed from the settings for the app outside of the app. Presumably using Root.plist. I will try and make this clearer in my question.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. If you have really seen it done before, you can look up inside the app's bundle for the actual plist file and try to work it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks Rog - i used iExplorer to look at the Settings.bundle file in the purchased app that had this working: It is complex but here is how it is laid out.

Root.plist:

```
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Terms &amp; Conditions</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSChildPaneSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Your Terms heading</string>
        <key>File</key>
        <string>Terms</string>
    </dict>
```

Terms.plist

```
<dict>
<key>StringsTable</key>
<string>Root</string>
<key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Terms1</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Terms2</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>Terms3</string>
    </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

en.lproj/Root.strings

```
"Terms1" = "iPhone Application Terms";
"Terms2" = "These terms blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah ";
"Terms3" = "The blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah .";
```

Comment: I am following this and in the Terms.plist when I specify `<string>Terms1</string>` when I view it on the device it just says "Terms1" when I click on "Terms". I have added the string to the Root.strings file. Has this process changed since 2011?

Answer (score -1):

Use a UIWebView in a view controller and feed it your terms & conditions formatted in HTML.  It's that easy.

The HTML can reside locally or on a server. Customers don't need to know it's HTML-formatted page because your view controller won't have an address bar in it.